How to update a firewall redirect rule in OpenWrt programmatically using UCI knowing only the name
My program has previously made a redirect rule..
uci add firewall redirect
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].dest='lan'
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].target='DNAT'
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].name='transmission'
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].src='wan'
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].src_dport='"$port"'
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].dest_ip='192.168.1.5'
uci set firewall.@redirect[-1].dest_port='"$port"'
uci commit firewall
service firewall restart

I need to programmatically update this rule periodically but I don't understand where the handle is.  I can't be sure this will be the last [-1] rule added.  Surely, there is a way for me to create a handle when creating the rule?  The only info that will be consistent is the name I've given the rule but it doesn't seem like a handle.

What firewall? What OS? Etc., etc. Add more details please.

OpenWrt, it is in the tag

Adding a tag doesn't a good question make. You should include such details in the body of your question. If you don't like this site, then don't use it.

So you can give your rule a proper name right after creation like so..
uci add firewall redirect
uci rename firewall.@redirect[-1]=myportforward

And then, after uci commit firewall, you can use that handle for operations.
Examples..
uci del firewall.myportforward

or
uci set firewall.myportforward.src='wan'

